# How do you see what rails3 migrations have been run against a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I am merging a branch to master and have had migrations in each.

I'm trying to see how merged migrations work by applying them to a backup of production (PostgreSQL).

Two of my branch migrations create a table, and the first is failing because the table already exists.

This is odd because the master repo does not have that migration.

The file db/schema.rb is ignored, so it was indicating the table existed from earlier migrations on the development database.  I remove it, and again see the table existing, so it appears I have run it against the wrong database locally.

So how does one find the list of migrations that have been run.  rake:db:version shows only the latest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rake db:migrate:status

# up      20131010170722  Devise create users
# up      20131015094519  Create customers
# down    20131121061642  Remove fileds from quantitative parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

The git branch is for code. But db is the same no matter what branch you are in.

If you have run migration in branch, you'll see the db change in master. That's normal behaviour.

For development db, that's easy, just run `rake db:reset` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score -1):

`rake db:version` will indeed show you the latest migration that's run. You can more or less assume that all earlier migrations have been run, but if you want to be sure the migration you're looking at has been executed, you can evaluate the contents of the `schema_migrations` table that will list the timestamps of all *succesfully* executed migrations.

I stress *successfully*, because that might be your problem here. If a migration fails in the middle of executing the migration (e.g. after creating a table), the migration will not be listed in `schema_migrations`, but it cannot roll back. I've explained that before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948862/rails-pending-migration-in-rake-dbtestprepare/17949009#17949009)), so I now shamelessly quote myself:

> `rake db:migrate` will tell you about the error by printing an error trail and saying "later migrations cancelled". It might seem logical that it would undo the changes and revert to its previous state, but that would be tricky because it doesn't always know what that previous state would be. Consider a migration in which you also process data. Or a migration in which you remove multiple columns. It would have to make assumptions (if it can) and that could leave you with much worse results.

Take a look at your database, I suspect the table indeed already exists, but if you take a look at the migration in which it's created, you might be able to find why the migration itself failed (*after* creating the table). If you can't, please share so we can take a look at it.

Comment: I'd very much like to know why this answer would warrant my very first downvote on SO. If I'm wrong, I'd like to learn from it.